# Creating a USB to RS485 converter with FT232RL chip

Tags: communication, ftdi

I want to create a USB to RS485 converter with auto switching between transmitting and receiving the data.  I found this circuit schematic on the internet.

[image]

My question is,
Do we have to program EEPROM of the FT232RL before using it or I can directly  mount it on the circuit
as shown in schematic and it will work?

Comment: Would http://www.ftdichip.com/Products/Cables/USBRS485.htm be a better solution?

Comment: I know, but they are costly.Even I have bought some converters http://sintech.cn/rs232%20rs485%20converter/STUB003B.html
But they are only sending the data but not receiving it.
It has almost the same circuitry. And, I think problem is in FTDI chip they used. So, I am here to find solution to my problem.

Comment: Why do you think you would need to change the EEPROM?

Comment: Because I have doubt, without some configuration how the same chip will work with both RS232 and RS485 converters. Because, for RS485 ICs like Max485, you need to trigger the driver pin  in order to switch between Tx and Rx mode. How FT232RL achieve that or does it have some pin for that purpose only? I think, the pins with prefix CBUS are used for triggering the enable pin of Max485 which should be configured for it. Because, different USB to RS485 circuits uses different "CBUS" pin for that purpose!

Comment: http://www.ftdichip.com/Support/Documents/DataSheets/ICs/DS_FT232R.pdf page 33 says that CBUS2 - TXDEN (RS485 direction select) Default configuration of CBUS2 – Transmit data enable for RS485 is enabled.

Comment: Oh yes, thanks. But then, why the connectors, I bought, not receiving the data, but only sending it? Please help me to solve this. I have bought 15 of them, spend 200$ on them :(

Comment: You can buy dual purpose (232/485) FTDI-chipped boards from eBay for peanuts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Document ftdichip.com/Support/Documents/DataSheets/ICs/DS_FT232R.pdf, page 33 says that CBUS2 - TXDEN (RS485 direction select)

Default configuration of CBUS2 – Transmit data enable for RS485 is enabled.

Check the pins used to enable the TXDEN.
[image]

Comment: FTDI are using CBUS2 and CBUS3, The design you have is using CBUS2 and CBUS4. That could be the problem.

Comment: Actually, that is not the schematic of my sintech converter. In my sintech converter, both DE and RE pins are short and connected to CBUS2. And it is a RS485/RS422 converter. So, there are two parellel RS485 circuits. In which RO pins of both MAX485 ICs goes into two pins of 3 pin regulator and 3rd pin goes to RXD  pin of FT232R. So, is that the reason why it's not receiving the data?

Comment: Thanks, I just bypassed that regulator and voila. It is working perfectly. Thanks, it happened because of your reply. Thanks, once again, you saved my 200 bucks. I thought, all 15 converters are waste now :P

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this also, you can use the FT232R directly without changing settings in it

You can control the functionality of each "CBUS" IO pin using the FT_PROG configuration utility

Setting them as this makes following possible:
C2 = TXEN on the RS485 tranceiver
C3 = PWREN# = \RE on the tranceiver, this will be "echo enabled mode"
C3 = TXEN = \RE on the tranceiver, this will be "echo disabled mode"

Hope this is helpfull